# Hudson server always stopped every morning day

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, hudson

I've got this regular problem every morning that my build server (Hudson) is always stopped every morning so I have to manually start it, is there any reason why or any location that I can started to look for the error message?

Here's the error diagnostic that I did:

```
ascari:~# ps -ef | grep -i hud
root      5959  5944  0 09:00 pts/0    00:00:00 grep -i hud

ascari:~# cd /etc/init.d

ascari:/etc/init.d# ./hudson start

ascari:/etc/init.d# ps -ef | grep -i hud
hudson    6004     1  0 09:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/daemon --name=hudson --    inherit --env=HUDSON_HOME=/var/lib/hudson --output=/var/log/hudson/hudson.log --    user=hudson --pidfile=/var/run/hudson/hudson.pid -- /usr/bin/java -Xms512m -Xmx1    024m -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.domain.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttp.nonProxyHo    sts="localhost|ascari|*.domain.com" -jar /usr/share/hudson/hudson.war --webroo    t=/var/run/hudson/war
hudson    6005  6004 48 09:00 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/java -Xms512m -Xmx1024m     -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.domain.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=    "localhost|ascari|*.domain.com" -jar /usr/share/hudson/hudson.war --webroot=/v    ar/run/hudson/war
root      6008  5944 14 09:01 pts/0    00:00:00 grep -i hud

ascari:/etc/init.d# df -k -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             327M  125M  185M  41% /
tmpfs                 1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                   10M   96K   10M   1% /dev
tmpfs                 1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda9             4.7G  295M  4.1G   7% /home
/dev/sda8             4.2G  155M  3.8G   4% /tmp
/dev/sda5             4.6G  3.0G  1.4G  69% /usr
/dev/sda6              65G   32G   30G  52% /var

ascari:/etc/init.d# uname -a
Linux ascari 2.6.26-2-686 #1 SMP Sun Jun 21 04:57:38 UTC 2009 i686 GNU/Linux

ascari:/etc/init.d#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rescheduling the project build solve the problem.
The Hudson process was killed by the Linux kernel due to the memory over consumption.

Comment: I am facing the same issue right now. Really weird. The server is down every morning and restart at 5pm.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the logfile (referenced above) and set the `--logfile` argument (as documented [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2009/02/10/hudson-now-good-behaving-unix-daemon)) ?

Comment: ah..., where is the log file referenced location ?

Comment: Thanks man, it seems that the error log is in /var/log/message, where it said:[<c015903e>] oom_kill_process+0x4f/0x195
[<c0159468>] out_of_memory+0x14e/0x17f
[<c02b99ca>] error_code+0x72/0x78 it caused by too many projects compiled at the same time therefore rescheduling every project to have interval of 30 minutes do the trick and it solved now.

Comment: Excellent! Glad that sorted it